# Consulta SQL - Filtrar campos

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
page         sessionid  
home         5237       
results      5237           
details      5237           
payment      5237           
black friday 2587   
results      2587
payment      2587
```

Estoy intentando mostrar aquellas sesiones que tuvieron como page home y payment (las dos). He hecho lo siguiente:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE page = 'home' AND 'payment'
```

Sin embargo, no obtengo resultado. Creo que se debe a que page no puede tener al mismo tiempo por un mismo registro estos dos valores. Pero no se me occurre nada más.

La respuesta debería ser:

5237

Gracias

Comment: Delimita en las etiquetas aquella que refleje que usas de manera específica, es decir o mysql o sql server

Comment: Perdon! Ya esta hecho

Comment: debes usar la clausula IN... y no se puede escribir campo = valor and valor.. en ese caso seria campo = valor and campo = valor, pero como bien decis, un campo no puede tener dos valores al mismo tiempo.

Comment: @gbianchi , y no seria mejor usar un or.

Comment: @Japv tambien... hace lo mismo que un IN...

Comment: pero si es un OR/IN entonces apareceran todos aquellos que tengan uno u otro pero no necesariamente los dos que es lo que se pide @gbianchi

Comment: Mmm, si aparecen los dos

Comment: @Japv no lo entiendo. Si yo pongo IN('payment','home') me van a salir las siguientes sesiones 5237 y cualquier otra que también tenga payment o home. Sólo quiero las que tengan los dos.

Comment: A ver si te entiendo tu quieres que solamente salgan payment y home, pero además que se cumpla que la sesión sea 5237?

Comment: @Japv si hago lo que tu estás diciendo con IN o OR en la tabla de arriba obtendré los resultados 5237 y 2587. Sólo debería obtener 5237 ya que existe un registro en el que hay home y el otro payment.

Comment: Al  final nunca entendí lo que querías decir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Podrías hacer un JOIN con la misma tabla, de modo que solo te daría un resultado si la sesión tuvo como page esos dos valores

```
SELECT * FROM tabla as t1 JOIN tabla as t2 ON t1.sessionid = t2.sessionid
WHERE t1.page = 'home' AND t2.page = 'payment'
```

Answer (score 0):

Si solamente quieres filtrar pocos resultados podrias utilizar un OR. Esto funcionaria para tu caso espefico y tendrias una query reducida pero en el caso de manipular varios resultados seria poco útil

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE page = 'home' OR page = 'payment';
```

Comment: Esto no da el resultado esperado, probablemente te haga falta re-leer la pregunta.